# ObjectId changes when object is selected?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've created an object in mongo that has a customerId property:

```
ObjectId("5631366e47da4eb120e5bf3a")
```

However, i noticed a sub-select using that object Id wasn't working, and when querying my object.customerId I instead get:

```
Object {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: "V16nGÚN± å¿:"}
```

Which doesn't match. Why is my object Id different upon selecting?

Comment: Are you saying you are doing a `find({customerId:objectId("5631366e47da4eb120e5bf3a")})`? That wouldn't work because you should be querying by `_id`, not `customerid`

Comment: It's apparently reading the hexadecimal ASCII value of every character. 56=V, 31=1, 36=6, 6e=n,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is returning the raw ObjectID. According to the [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) this is a 12-byte BSON type, constructed using:

- a 4-byte value representing the seconds since the Unix epoch,
- a 3-byte machine identifier,
- a 2-byte process id, and
- a 3-byte counter, starting with a random value.

You can convert `Object {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: "V16nGÚN± å¿:"}` to the usual 24 char hex string (5631366e47da4eb120e5bf3a) by calling its `.toString` function. Alternatively, Mongoose documents also have a `.id` getter that returns the 24 char hex as a string value, see this comment on the [Mongoose Github Repository](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/548#issuecomment-2245903)